How to preserve state in Blazor 8 with static SSR
I have Blazor Web App, interactive mode is Auto and location per page/component.
Since App, Routes and Layouts are rendered statically on the server, every navigation causes BrowserInfo(registred as Scoped) is injected new. So how to achieve persisting state with Auto render mode without Singleton service to have this state only for one user?
The thing is, i want to set set layout in Routes.razor based on detectiong iframe
The project cannot have globally available interactivity (such as Blazor Server).
I have it like this right know:
App.razor:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorAppAuto.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

    <script>
        if (window.self !== window.top) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('iframe', 'true');
        }
        else {
            sessionStorage.setItem('iframe', 'true');
        }

        const iframeValue = sessionStorage.getItem('iframe');
        const url = new URL(window.location);
        if (url.searchParams.get('iframe') !== iframeValue) {
            url.searchParams.set('iframe', iframeValue);
            window.location.href = url.toString();
        }
    </script>
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>
<body>
    <Routes />
</body>
</html>

Routes.razor
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly"
        AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly, typeof(BasketApp.UI.DependencyInjection).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="routeData" >
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="BrowserInfo.IsIframe ? typeof(FrameLayout) : typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated is not true)
                {
                    // <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <BasketApp.UI.Components.Common.ErrorsAlert 
                        Errors="@([ErrorOr.Error.Forbidden(description: "You are not authorized to access this resource.")])" />
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                Authorizing...
            </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
</Router>
@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "iframe")] public bool IFrame { get; set; }
    @inject BrowserInfo BrowserInfo;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (BrowserInfo.IsIframe) return;
        BrowserInfo.IsIframe = IFrame;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}

or second choice is not setting layouts in Routes but in MainLayout
@inject BrowserInfo BrowserInfo

  @if (!BrowserInfo.IsIframe)
  {
      <NavMenu @rendermode=PreferredRenderMode />
  }

[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "iframe")] public bool IFrame { get; set; }
    @inject BrowserInfo BrowserInfo;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (BrowserInfo.IsIframe) return;
        BrowserInfo.IsIframe = IFrame;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }


Oh the Blazor gotchas! Plan B because you can't use session storage to share between your backend and client apps! I was doing the same thing and switched to InteractiveServer because I realized all of my services were being registered twice for each project. Maybe PersistentComponentState will help you.

PersistentComponentState may help you.  "The project cannot have globally available interactivity (such as Blazor Server)."  Are you sure?  [Personal View] Auto with per page/component rendering is an absolute dog's breakfast where the complexity necessary to build the application will quickly spiral out of control.  You can see my personal [Early days of Net8] take on it here - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Posts/Mongrel-Blazor.html

SSR works in server, can not access browser storage.
Interactive Server/WASM can accesss browser storage via js interop.
So based on your needs. I thinks you could use "Server-side session storage" with "Client-side session storage" together. They use the same session id, but store values in different place.
To use server session storage, in the "server project" program.cs add
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
...
app.UseSession();

Then in the App.razor, you could save the iframe value to server session at the same time.
...
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (window.self !== window.top) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('iframe', 'true');
        }
        else {
            sessionStorage.setItem('iframe', 'true');
        }

        const iframeValue = sessionStorage.getItem('iframe');
        const url = new URL(window.location);
        if (url.searchParams.get('iframe') !== iframeValue) {
            url.searchParams.set('iframe', iframeValue);
            window.location.href = url.toString();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext httpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "iframe")] public string IFrame { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (IFrame != null)
        {
           //save IFrame value to server session storage.
            httpContext.Session.SetString("iframe", IFrame);
            Console.WriteLine(httpContext.Session.Id+": set iframe to "+ IFrame);
        }
    }
}

Then in the "client project" , install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.2.2 to make HttpContext availabe when SSR. Then you could get value from server/client session storage depending on the render mode in Routes.razor
...
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using System.Text
@inject IJSRuntime js
...
DefaultLayout="IsIframe=="true" ? typeof(FrameLayout) : typeof(MainLayout)"
...
@code {
    private string IsIframe = "";

    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext httpContext { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (httpContext != null)
        {
            byte[] byteArray;
            httpContext.Session.TryGetValue("iframe", out byteArray);

            if (byteArray != null)
            {
                IsIframe = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
                Console.WriteLine(httpContext.Session.Id + ": get iframe value " + IsIframe);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IsIframe = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", "iframe");
        }
    }
}

Some explaination:
In the server project you could get session value using httpContext.Session.GetString("iframe"). But in client project, this method is not available. You have to use httpContext.Session.TryGetValue ot extrat out the byteArrary, then encoding it back to string.
If user doesn't login. The sessionId will still change when render mode change. Then you couldn't get the value from the right session storage. Cookie storage maybe a good way for anonymous. You could visit cookie by httpcontext.request/response.cookie. or js interop similar to session storage.
